# ViewController containing UIView which is a MKMapView

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview

I have a view controller and I want part of it to be a `UIView` which I would put custom `UIView`s that I've created in and change them throughout the run of the app.

I have my view controller and in the storyboard I put in it a `UIView`.
I created a custom `UIView` that has a `MKMapView`:

```
@interface MapUIView : UIView <CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapCtl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *address;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLGeocoder *reverseGeo;

@end
```

Now what I want to do is to set the `UIView` in the main view controller to my custom `UIView` and that it will show a `MKMapView`.

I'm kind of new to this, so if you see anything wrong with my implementation please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Select the view, then select the identity inspector in the utilities panel on the right-hand side.  You can change it to be a custom subclass of `UIView` there.

Note that simply creating a `MKMapView` property on the view doesn't actually create an instance of `MKMapView` or add it as a subview, so you'll need to either do that programmatically or by adding it in the storyboard.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer.

What I did is create a NIB and creating it as type MapUIView, Then I filled it up with MKMapView.

now, what I have is a view controller that has a navigation bar and a UIView, and I want to fill that UIView with my new NIB so that it would look like the map layer is part of that ViewController even though it's a separate UIView..

Thanks,
Matt